# How do I solve the missing right parenthesis error in this SQL script?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to update a table I created called XJ9 Employee by adding 1000 to the salary column of the tabel where the "EMP_DEPT" is equal to 11
[XJ9TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf43Z.png)

This was my query

```
UPDATE EMP_SALARY set (SALARY+1000))
FROM XJ9_EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMP_DEPT=11;
```

but I keep getting this error about there being a missing right parentheses and I'm not sure where it is.

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: This isn't MySQL

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE xj9table 
       SET emp_salary=emp_salary+1000
WHERE  EMP_DEPT=11;
```